# How to add user roles on Signup?

Tags: django

**my models.py**

```
ROLES = (
    (1, 'student'),
    (2, 'creator'),
    (3, 'mentor')
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLES, default=1)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

**views.py**

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

I want to assign a role to every user which signs up, to make some permissions to restrict some type of users, i want t know how to add that role field in the signup so that a role can be given when a user registers and then permissions can be made accordingly, or if there is some better way to do it

Comment: Whats the problem you're facing?

Comment: I have added a role to the User model, I want to ask how to assign that a role to the user on signup

Comment: Any reason why you didn't the field to `SignUpForm` in forms.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add 'role' in your fields. It should work for you.

```
 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'role' )
```